# Does hashing a hash of a password over and over again increase its security?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I've heard of password cracking attacks using a list of commonly used passwords. Suppose in my situation, I can never be sure about the strength of the password, that a user inputs to my interface. So if I compute the SHA 256 hash of the user inputted password, then hash the hash again **n** times will that increase its overall probability of NOT being cracked ? If so what should be a reasonable value of **n**.  Thanks everyone in advance!!!

Comment: Congratulation, you partially reinvented iterated password hashing as practiced for half a century, and still practiced (with some critical improvements, including salting) in e.g. PBKDF2. But there has been theoretical progress since, like bcrypt, scrypt, Argon2, Balloon hashing. The functionality is available as a library or built in some languages. Don't roll your own crypto !

Answer (score 1):

What your describing is the core of many password hashing algorithms like bcrypt or pbkdf2. However, these are all complicated functions which don't *just iterate*. They are very commonly used with salt. If you would hash a password as you described *n* times, a reasonable choice would be bigger then 100.000.

However this is only for storing the password. If you would do this for, say, a website, it would take about 2 seconds. And if you're clients arent finding it nice to wait that long, you should lower it.

Comment: Please review your post before hitting the button, that last sentence has a certain, uh, lack of words?